# Android Service's method onDestroy called before Bluetooth scanning ends

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I have a problem that I start a service with an Intent, in `onCreate()` method register `BroadcastReceiver` and then in `onDestroy()` unregister the `BroadcastReceiver`. In Method `onHandleIntent()` I start discovery for bluetooth devices. THe problem is, that I my `BroadcastReceiver` is destroyed before any device is found so I cant really do anything with the `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND` intent. I tried to move `startDiscovery()` to `onCreate()` but no results. My code looks like this:

```
public class BluetoothService extends IntentService{

private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
private final String SMART_TOKEN_ADDRESS = "F0:E7:7E:5F:63:70";
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("BLUETOOTH","found it!");
    }

};

public BluetoothService() {
    super("BluetoothService");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    Log.v("SERVICE", "Just got created");
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    btAdapter.startDiscovery();
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    Log.v("BLUETOOTH", "Discovery just started");
    //btAdapter.startDiscovery();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("BLUETOOTH","Just got destroyed!");
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);        
}
```

}

Log looks like this:
  1. Just got created
  2. Discovery just started
  3. Just got destroyed!
  4. Received android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND

Thanks for help!
T.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because after handling all the requests, the service is stoped. From documentation: "Stops the service after all start requests have been handled, so you never have to call stopSelf()."

So, you should use wait or other command to tell the worker thread to wait the execution, if you want to use service.

Please, refer to the documentation about services: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html